# Azure SendGrid is Paused

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid

My SendGrid account in Azure is showing as 'Paused' and it won't be able to send out email. How do I start it from Azure portal?

Last month, we ran out of quota and Azure stopped everything, including the marketplace app we had, SendGrid.
I tried contacting SendGrid support, they can't do anything, the support guy said 'it's locked and I can't do anything.'. Azure support wants me to pay for 'service plan'. I tried old and new portal, no luck. Old portal doesn't even show my SendGrid account.

Anybody has this problem before?
Is it safe to just delete my SendGrid app and create a new one?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacted Azure support about a week ago and last update (2 days ago) was that they were still working on it.

I resolved the issue by creating a new SendGrid account (through SendGrid directly). You still get to send emails for free, but only for 12k emails / month, instead of through Azure where you get 25k / month.

But at least, by signing up with SendGrid directly, their support has more control over my account while with Azure, SendGrid support can't help me troubleshoot my SendGrid / Azure account.

Also, I think it's important to note that by using SendGrid under Azure, although you are getting 25k emails for free, **you still going to be billed for the compute hours you use to send those emails out**. This is stated in their terms and condition when you create a new SendGrid account under Azure Portal.

By signing up with SendGrid directly, you will also avoid being billed by Azure for sending emails out. You will still be billed for whatever running your code to initiate the sending, but not the sending itself.

Overall, I think signing up with SendGrid directly is better for us.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely answered your own question. If you hit your quota you must upgrade to keep using the service. It is safe to delete and create a new one but you will need to re-configure your sendgrid credentials in your app.

Also, I'm not sure that re-creating a new one will reset your quota.

Comment: I hit my quota last month and the problem came after the new quota is in effect. So, technically with new quota, I can use whatever I had before that.

Answer (score 1):

Did you pay your Azure bill? I discovered that the client's Azure account was suspended for non-payment. While database services were still available, the SendGrid service was paused. Surprisingly this was not overwhelmingly obvious when logged into the Azure portal. It was not until I removed and attempted to create another instance of the SendGrid service that I discovered the Azure account was suspended.